# Assembler - How to pass integer to printf?

Tags: assembly, x86

I saw two diffrent way to pass integer in assmbler: the one by [eax], the second by eax. 
I'll give an example:

```
section .rodata
print_int_str: "%d"
%macro     print_int  1
     push %1
     push print_int_str
     call printf
     add esp, 8
%endmacro
```

as I understood, we can use `print_int eax`, and also `print_int [eax]`.

What is the difrrence between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_int eax
```

will print you the value of `eax`

```
print_int [eax]
```

will use the value of `eax` as an address and will print the value that is stored at this address

so you can either put the integer into `eax` and use (any other reg will work too)

```
print_int eax
```

or if you have a variable you can do

```
print_int [var]; or
print_int [reg]; with regs value = address of var
```

Comment: Thats I know, I asked about integer. Thanks.